# If $x\in \mathbb{R}$ then show that $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: \Im(z) < x\} =A$ is open.

Tags: complex-analysis

THE RED LINE IS $ \Im(z) = x$

[image]

Now, my proof is as follows,

Let $z' \in A$, then take $\epsilon = x - \Im(z')>0$

Now let $w \in D_{\epsilon}(z')$ and suppose $w \notin A$ then

$$\epsilon > |z'-w| \geq|\Im(z)-\Im(w)| = \color{red}{\Im(w) - \Im(z')} \geq x - \Im(z') = \epsilon$$ A contradiction. This seems all good, but when I thought about it, the red bit seems fishy. For example, in my "diagram", $\Im(w) < Im(z')$, Is there a way to fix this way of proof or is it flawed from the outset?

You see in my diagram if I chosen $w$ above 
$z'$ then it would have been ok.

EDIT:

There are some cool answers already, but I need to show that it is true using the definition.

A set $A$ is open if for all $z \in A$ there exists $r > 0$ such that $D_r(z) \subset A$

Comment: The red bit is fine. If $w \in D_{\epsilon}(z')$, then there are two possibilities, 1) $\Im w \leqslant \Im z'$, but then you immediately have $w\in A$ from $\Im w \leqslant \Im z' < x$, or 2) $\Im w > \Im z'$, and then you have $\lvert \Im w - \Im z'\rvert = \Im w - \Im z'$. At the point where you assume $w \notin A$ - to obtain a contradiction - you rule out the first possibility. Your diagram matches situation 1), however. So the thing is that your diagram doesn't match your proof. No biggie, just an illustration of the fact that pictures can often be misleading.

Comment: Ahh thanks! This is the answer I would have wanted originally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First way**

Your set is $$\mathbb R\times ]-\infty ,x[$$
(or in fact, homeomorphic to $\mathbb R\times ]-\infty ,x[$, but it doesn't really matter here) which is obviously open.

**Second way**

Let $z=u+iv$ s.t. $v<x$. Take $\varepsilon=\frac{x-v}{2}>0$. If $$\omega \in B(z,\varepsilon)=\{re^{i\theta}+z\mid r\leq \varepsilon, \theta\in [0,2\pi]\},$$

in particular $$\Im(\omega )=\frac{re^{i\theta}+z-re^{-i\theta}-\bar z}{2i}=r\sin(\theta)+v\leq \varepsilon+ v = \frac{x-v}{2}+v=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{v}{2}<\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{2}=x.$$
Therefore $\omega \in \{z\in \mathbb C\mid \Im(z)<x\}$, what prove the claim.

Comment: That's fine, but I have to show that it is open.

Comment: The fact that $\mathbb R$ is open is obvious. The fact that $]-\infty ,x[$ is open, is also obvious, the fact that a product of open is open is obvious. What else ? :-)

Comment: I wish my prof would accept that. :(

Comment: @HMPARTICLE: I edited my post. I hope it will be fine for you now.

Comment: I am not understanding the last equality, shout it equal $r\sin(\theta) + v$?

Comment: @HMPARTICLE: It's normal, it was wrong. I corrected it. Is it fine for you now ?

Comment: Yes, I was questioning life for a moment there! THanks Surb :)

Answer (score 1):

The function $\Im\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and the set is the inverse image of $(-\infty,x)$, which is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

If you don't like this, show that, if $\Im(z)<x$, then the disk $D_\varepsilon(z,)$, where $\varepsilon=(x-\Im(z))/2$, is contained in the set $A$.

Comment: I like your answer !